# Does Spring MVC 4 consider Jackson annotation of parameters?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

There is a class as follow:

```
class A {
    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    String firstName;
}
```

And a MVC controller:

```
public A createNewA(A a){
    ...
}
```

I expect the following REST create an instance of A with first name:

POST: /path/to/resouce
   Form data
       first_name: Ali

But the first name is null. By the way, the following request works fine:

POST: /path/to/resouce
   Form data
       firstName: Ali

As I debug, ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor is used to resolve parameter and where objects are Considered as bean.

Is there any parameter resolver to check jackson annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default resolver of spring-mvc to convert method arguments to bean objects uses exactly name of fields in the bean to search in key-values sent in the request. If you want another behavior you should implement yours resolver. To do that you should implement `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` which has two main method.

In your case which you want resolver behaves similar to jackson deserializer you could implement such resolver as follow. This resolver create an map of key-values from parameters of sent request then uses jackson mapper to fill a bean object by given key-values:

```
public class BeanObjectParameterResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Inject
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
            NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        Iterator<String> enumName = webRequest.getParameterNames();
        while(enumName.hasNext()){
            String name  = enumName.next();
            params.put(name, webRequest.getParameter(name));
        }

        // jackson 1.9 and before
        // mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        // or jackson 2.0
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        Object obj = mapper.convertValue(params, parameter.getParameterType());

        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return !BeanUtils.isSimpleProperty(parameter.getParameterType());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jackson is used to parse and serialize JSON. You're sending x-www-form-urlencoded data. So Jackson is irrelevant.

If you send a JSON request body, and thus annotate the a parameter with `@RequestBody`, then Jackson will be used, and will honor the annotation.